# redirect emails to a web URL

Tags: php, mysql, database, email

I want to develop a system in which I want to allow users to create an account on my website. When they create account, they will get an username. Now I want some method by which they can forward their emails to this username or some webpage. So that I can save those emails into database after some processing.

Comment: And what problems have you encountered so far?

Comment: This sounds like a "do it for me" question...

Comment: How does what you're doing benefit the user at all? If they have an email address already, they already have a means of reading their emails? All you're doing is storing their private stuff in *another* place

Answer (score 0):

look at php piping on cPanel - this allows you to set-up a catch-all email address and then process that via a php script.

From this you can check the 'too' address (which will be user.id@yourdomain.com) and will then be able to deal with it appropriately.

Please note as you seem to be quite new given the question I would recommend learning an awful lot more before tackling this - receiving email and decoding it is HARD!

I spent 8 weeks building a system to allow me to give clients their own email system at my account as part of a CRM - and I borrowed 80% of the code from [roundcube](http://roundcube.net/)

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

To re-create an email accepting and storage solution in PHP might become tedious work.
I suggest to install standard tools for this job or be prepared for a whole lot of work.

1. Create a new user via webinterface boils down to executing `adduser` or `useradd` on the shell. There are already several tools out there (webmin and others), which provide the functionality to create new email accounts via a webinterface.
2. `apt-get install postfix, dovecot, mysql, roundcube, webmin`
   That enables your server to route emails to your desired mysql location for further processing. With http://roundcube.net/ you can provide an easy and extendable email webinterface to your users.

This article is a good read: https://library.linode.com/email/postfix/postfix2.9.6-dovecot2.0.19-mysql